# Computing Lebesgue-integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a measure space. $f,g$ are two non negative step functions.

$f=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \chi_{A_j} \ and \ g=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \chi_{B_k}$

It holds that: $\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j =X \ and \  \bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k=X$

Futhermore it holds: $A_i\cap A_j= \emptyset \ and \ B_k \cap B_l=\emptyset$

Let now be $E_{jk}= A_j \cap B_k \cap E$ with $E \in \mathcal{A}$

How do I get the following result without using linearity: $$\int_{E_{jk}}(f+g) d\mu =(a_j+b_k)\cdot \mu(E_{jk}) $$

Comment: To begin with, you will need the $A_i$s and $B_i$s disjoint ie $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$

Comment: Yes. I forgot that. They are disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in E_{jk}$ we have $x \in A_j$ and $x \in B_k$, hence $f(x)=a_j$ and $g(x)=b_k.$

This gives: $f+g$ is constant $=a_j+b_k$ on $E_{jk}$, therefore

$$\int_{E_{jk}}(f+g) d\mu =(a_j+b_k)\cdot \mu(E_{jk}).$$

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in E_{jk}$ then $f(x)+g(x)=a_j+b_k$. Hence linearity of the integral is not required.

Comment: Thank you very much:)